# How to preload data in Sapper app from Prismic API

Tags: svelte, sapper

In my Sapper App I want to preload from Prismic API using their SDK ('prismic-javascript)

I followed the docs for preloading content. Yet the docs only provide the preloading through the this.fetch function. I want to connect to my Prismic repository with the Prismic SDK. But it doesn't give me back any data at all.

I also tried the this.fetch method with JSONplaceholder. That just works fine. Even requiring the Prismic-SDK the "old way" doesn't work:

```
var Prismic = require("prismic-javascript")
```

So this is what my code looks like:

```
<script context="module">
  import Prismic from "prismic-javascript";
  const apiEndpoint = "https://my-repository.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2";

  export async function preload(page, session) {
    const api = await Prismic.getApi(apiEndpoint, { req });
    const data = await api.getSingle("portfolio");
    return { data };
  }
</script>
```

This code should populate the data variable with the API-data. But it doesn't. Is there anyone who could help me out here? Thanks!

Comment: you are passing a `req` variable to your `Prismic.getApi` method, however `req` doesn't seem to be defined. Is it a mistake from copy/pasting code for the question ?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment! You are right, the req variable isn't used. Yet, it doesn't work without that variable either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one works if you don't need the req object from Prismic:

```
  import Prismic from "prismic-javascript";
  const apiEndpoint = "https://my-repository.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2";

  export async function preload({ params, query }) {
    const api = await Prismic.getApi(apiEndpoint);
    const data = await api.getSingle("portfolio");

    return { data };
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I checked the prismic documentation, and as it turns out the `getApi` method requires you to give it `req` in the second argument.

`Req` is the `request` argument in nodejs server calls. You can't access it from the `preload` method.

What you need to do, is create a [server route](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Server_routes), from which you will be able to use the Prismic API.

```html
<script context="module">
  export async function preload(page, session) {
    const data = await this.fetch('/prismic/portfolio');
    return { data };
  }
</script>
```

with a `prismic/[slug].js` server route

```
import Prismic from "prismic-javascript";
const apiEndpoint = "https://my-repository.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2";

export async function get(req, res, next) {
    const { slug } = req.params;

    const api = await Prismic.getApi(apiEndpoint, { req });
    const data = await api.getSingle(slug);

    if (article !== null) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```